# How to change textView frames using pinch gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I added UITextView programatically to a view and added pinch gesture to textview. In pinch gesture I got zoom in zoom out works perfectly. But here UITextView transforms its size. Instead of that I want to change its frames. With my code textview height is changing, width is not changing.

```
    UITextView *pinchView = (UITextView*)pinch.view;

    UIFont *font = pinchView.font;
    CGFloat pointSize = font.pointSize;
    NSString *fontName = font.fontName;

    pointSize = ((pinch.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;

    if (pointSize < 13) pointSize = 13;
    if (pointSize > 30) pointSize = 30;

    pinchView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];


    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(viewWidth, viewHeight);
    CGSize contentSize = [pinchView sizeThatFits:maximumSize];
    CGRect frame = pinchView.frame;
    frame.size.height = contentSize.height;
    pinchView.frame = frame;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have this `frame.size.height = contentSize.height;` but you don't have anything thats changing the frames `width`

Comment: @Flexicoder in code I did't mention the width code. But I tried with Width also as like height. But I didn't get required result.